# Pie Chart using Chartjs in angularjs 1.5.8 with components not showing up in view

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-components

I want to create a dashboard like feature on my existing angular app using Chart.js. So, I created a view for the dashboard.

```
<md-content layout-padding layout-fill flex class="animated fadeIn">
    <div layout-padding>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">Dashboard</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
    </div>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <div>
        <md-grid-list md-cols-gt-md="12" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-md="8"
                      md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3"
                      md-gutter-gt-md="8px" md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" md-gutter="2px">
            <md-grid-tile md-colspan-gt-sm="3" md-rowspan-gt-sm="3">
               <pie-chart header="'Auths'" auth-counts="ctrl.authCounts" flex-gt-sm></pie-chart>
            </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

The dashboard controller is loaded from the route (`ui.router`). The controller is empty at the moment.

```
//router
.state('home.dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                controller: 'DashboardController as ctrl',
                templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Scripts/src/views/dashboard/dashboard.home.html'
            })

  function DashboardController() {

        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.$onInit = function () {

            console.log('testing');
            ctrl.authCounts = [800, 200];


        }

    }
```

Then, the component `pie-chart` looks like the following.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('chart')
        .component('pieChart', {
            controller: PieChartComponentController,
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/src/views/dashboard/pie.chart.template.html',
            bindings: {
                header: '<',
                authCounts: '<'
            }
        });

    PieChartComponentController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function PieChartComponentController($timeout) {

        var $ctrl = this;


        $ctrl.$onInit = function () {

            var myPieChart;
            var data;
        }

        $ctrl.isArrayEmpty = function (authCount) {

            if (!authCount) return true;
            return authCount.length === 0;

        }


        $ctrl.createChart = function () {
            var pieData = {
                labels: ["Purple","Green","Orange","Yellow"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                      data: [20, 40, 10, 30],
                      backgroundColor: ["#878BB6","#4ACAB4","#FF8153","#FFEA88"]
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext("2d");

            var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: pieData
            });


        } // end createChart()
    }
})();
```

And the `pie-chart` template looks like the following.

```
    <div layout-align="start center" ng-if="$ctrl.isArrayEmpty($ctrl.authCounts)">
        Not enough information available to create the chart.
    </div>

    <canvas id="myPieChart" width="250" height="250" ng-init="$ctrl.createChart()" ng-if="$ctrl.isArrayEmpty($ctrl.authCounts)" flex-gt-sm></canvas>

</md-card-content>
```

It seems like everything is fine, but the canvas height and width is 0 and the chart is not rendered.

However, if I remove the `pie-chart` component, and put the `<canvas>` element outside in the dashboard template and the data in the dashboard, it renders the chart. But that's not what I want to do, though. I need to have component for each type. So, what am I doing wrong that's causing this behavior?

I also tried `angular-chart.js` that showed the same behavior. If I put the `<canvas>` element in the dashboard template, it displays the chart but not from inside `pie-chart` element. I need help troubleshooting it. I'm definitely missing something here but can't figure out what. Is the canvas being rendered before the data is provided, or is there something going on that I'm overlooking (or oblivious about)?

Comment: isn't $onInit() angular 2.x syntax? Your question says you're using 1.5.x.

Comment: does `DashboardController` controller alias is `ctrl`?

Comment: Yes. I must've missed it to add the router. I'll update the question

Comment: @Ericson578, $onInit is also in 1.5.x. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: I had to put `ng-if="$ctrl.authCounts"` before the canvas is created. Soon as I added that, it worked.